# Rails In line edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How can I edit the following below in the index page? I would like to be able to inline edit and update the following the view has the index action

```
<% @request.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.message %>
  <%= s.date %>
<% end %>
```

Tried the gem best in place but i doesnt seem to work so whenever i tried 
 <%= best_in_place @request, :message %> it throws an error of unknown method :message. Isnt this `<%= best_in_place @request, :message %>` the same with this  `<%= s.message %>`

Does best in place work in rails version 5.1.4 and how can I make the inline edit to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does best in place work in rails version 5.1.4 and how can I make the
>   inline edit to work ?

Yes, it works, you need jQuery and to add the gem and JS libraries.

For jQuery:

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

Then in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
```

For best_in_place, add the gem in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Then the library in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require best_in_place
...

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

You see the best_in_place js right after jquery, and the initialization in the same file - you must add `//= require_tree .` for initializing in the same file.

Then in your view you need to pass the object and the attribute:

```
<% @request.each do |request| %>
  <%= best_in_place request, :message %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: i get an error of undefined method `message_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f1cb32834e0>:0x00007f1cb301b720>

Comment: Can you show me what's your actual code, raising that error now?

Comment: <%= best_in_place request, :message %>

Comment: I need to see the whole code, where does `request` come from.

Comment: Can I paste the whole code here? It comes from the controller @request = Friend.where(id: user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157660/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-john).